# docker-compose up with port mapping is not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple node js app with redis.
Docker version: `Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b`
`Dockerfile` for node js app is as follows:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

And my `docker-compose.yml` file is as follows.

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
  node-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '4001:8081'
```

I ran the command using `docker-compose up`.
It says application is running with no error logs.

`docker ps` shows this:

```
e87f02c0797b   counterapp-node-app   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   46 minutes ago   Up 46 minutes   0.0.0.0:4001->8081/tcp   counterapp-node-app-1
8791802aa776   redis                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 hours ago     Up 46 minutes   6379/tcp                 counterapp-redis-server-1
```

When I visit `http://localhost:4001` on my browser. It doesn't show up.

```
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.
```

I do not understand why this is not working.
Here is my `index.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');

const app = express();
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: 'redis-server',
  port: 6379,
});
client.set('visits', 0);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  client.get('visits', (err, visits) => {
    res.send('Number of visits ' + visits);
    client.set('visits', parseInt(visits) + 1);
  });
});

app.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 8081');
});
```

And here is `package.json`

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "redis": "2.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

And here is my folder structure.

```
└── counterapp
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    ├── index.js
    ├── package-lock.json
```

Comment: What does `npm start` actually do?  Is the listener in your Javascript code listening on port 4001, and on the special "all interfaces" address 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks fine. The port mapping

```
ports:
  - '4001:8081'
```

means: "map the host's port 4001 (localhost:4001) to the container's port 8081". So you need to make sure that `npm start` runs the server on port 8081 and address '0.0.0.0' (required to make the port 'exposable').

Comment: @wick3d I've just run your setup on my laptop (Mac Ventura) and it worked fine. There's something else in play here.

Comment: Weird, I deleted the folder and started the app again it works now.